# PHP form not performing action

Tags: php, forms, post

I'm trying to implement a basic login function in PHP on a website I'm making. I can't seem to make this form submit in any way, however.

There are some bootstrap styles but that shouldn't impede anything.

I have also not included much of the surrounding html code, and any includes.

```
<?php 
      $fname  = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
      echo $_POST["email"];
 ?>

<html>
<body>
<div class = 'card-body bg-dark container'>
    <form class = 'form-group' action = "<?php echo $fname; ?>" method = "post">
      <input type = 'email' class = 'form-control' placeholder = 'Example@website.com' name = "email"><br/>
      <input type = 'text' class = 'form-control' placeholder = 'Password' name = 'password'>
      <br/>
      <input type = "button" class = 'btn btn-block text-light dark-theme' value = "Forgot Password?">
      <input type = "button" class = 'btn btn-block text-light dark-theme' value = "Login" name = "submit">
      <input type = "button" class = 'btn btn-block text-light dark-theme' value = "Report an Issue">
    </form>
  </div>
  </body>
  </div>
```

I've looked at many examples but I can't make this work in my own code. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What's the output of `echo $fname`?

Comment: However, change the type of login button to be "submit" instead of button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no button with the type "`submit`".

Try to change this element :

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-block text-light dark-theme" value="Login" name="submit">
```

A type `button` does not trigger the form to be submitted.

Also, as pointed by [Funk Forty Niner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/funk-forty-niner), you have a *"undefined index"* notice thrown on this line :

```
echo $_POST["email"];
```

And should be :

```
if (isset($_POST["email")) {
    echo $_POST["email"];
}
```

Have a look to : [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display/21429652#21429652)

Comment: Right. Yet, you left out the part where they're creating an undefined index notice immediately on initial page load.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Absolutely right. I'll add to the anwser. Thanks a lot.